# Login en php no me deja acceder al sitio de administracion

Tags: php, session, server

Tengo un sitio web creado con PHP, HTML, JS, CS y phpMySql. Cuando tengo el sitio en localhost, puedo ingresar con el usuario creado. Pero cuando subí el sitio completo al server de *DonWeb*, al poner las credenciales, retorna un error de que son incorrectos. Pero en la base de datos existen. Probe el sitio en otro server, pero esta vez en el de Hostinger y el sistema funciona correctamente, pienso que tal vez sea un problema con el server de *DonWeb* y su certificado SSL.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST){
  include("./bd.php");
  //Recepcionamos los valores del formulario
  $usuario=(isset($_POST['usuario']))?$_POST['usuario']:"";
  $password=(isset($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:"";

  // Instruccion para listar los datos de MySql
  // Instruccion para validar datos
  $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT *, count(*) as n_usuario 
            FROM `tbl_usuarios`
            WHERE usuario=:usuario
            AND password=:password
            ");
  //insercion de los valores del usuario
  $sentencia->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario);
  $sentencia->bindParam(":password",$password);
  $sentencia->execute();

  $lista_usuarios=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

  if($lista_usuarios['usuario']>0){
      $_SESSION['usuario']=$lista_usuarios['usuario'];
      $_SESSION['logueado']=true;
      header("Location:index.php");
  }else{
    $mensaje_error="El usuario o la contraseña no son correctos";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ya verificaste que es lo que te trae de la DB **$lista_usuarios**?? ya que si pasa al **else** significa que **$lista_usuarios['usuario']** NO es mayor que 0.

Comment: Como verifico que me trae la lista usurios?

Comment: logre hacer pasar los datos del login cambiando el mayor que > por distinto de !==.

Answer (score 0):

En base a

> logre hacer pasar los datos del login cambiando el mayor que > por distinto de !==

Esa no sería la forma ideal de resolver tu problema, recuerda que siempre la [lógica](https://i.ibb.co/YT9WCNx/LOGIC.jpg) es lo más importante.

### Aprende a depurar tu Código

**$lista_usuarios** es un array, para verificar que es lo que trae puedes imprimirlo en pantalla

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
      print_r($lista_usuarios);
   echo '</pre>';
```

**$lista_usuarios['usuario']** NO ES UN NUMERO, es un string de un array (el nombre o usuario de la persona) así que no puede ser evaluado como numero diciendo en un if que si es mayor que 0. (A no ser que sea exactamente un numero del array resultado)

Por otro lado, si lo que querías desde un inicio es saber si el resultado de tu query **es Mayor que Cero**, entonces siempre debes pedirle a tu código que te diga el numero de registros recuperados.

Tomado de la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) para PDO.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
$count = $res->fetchColumn(); // Esto cuenta los resultados

print "Existen " .  $count . " registros.";
//Existen 2 registros.
```

Espero te ayude no solo en este problema, sino en todo tu aprendizaje.